# Adicionar conteúdo na posição do cursor com Froala editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, froala-editor

Tenho um campo textarea e um segundo campo *select*.
Quaro clicar em um determinado lugar da minha *textarea*, e logo depois escolher uma
das opções do meu campo select, e quero que essa opção que for escolhida(*um texto qualquer*), apareça no lugar que eu cliquei por ultimo na minha textarea.
    **Obs. *Minha aplicação é em Ruby on Rails e na minha textarea, uso o editor Froala Editor***

Comment: pode postar o codigo, ficara melhor para ajuda-lo

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um onclick no textarea para chamar uma função para pegar a posição do cursor e salvar em uma variável global.

Use o código:

```
 document.getElementById("IdTextarea").selectionStart;
```

Depois crie uma função que pegue o valor do select escolhido com onchange e selected index (ou do jeito que vc preferir) e insira o valor na posição coletada anteriormente.

```
conteudo = document.getElementById("IdTextarea").value;             
pt1 = conteudo.substring(0,pos); 
pt2 = conteudo.substring(pos);
document.getElementById("IdTextarea").value = pt1 + selecionado + pt2;
```

onde a variável pos é igual ao valor da posição do cursor que você coletou na outra função.